# How do I add files in a dictionary?

Tags: python, file-io

I am creating a small system where the person can login with a username and a password. The code would then check the text file that contains the username and the password on the same line.

I have no idea how to make this work thought. How come it is so complicated to create a simple login system based off of a text file with the details in it? I believe that it is my philosophy that is wrong and not the actual code.

I have used various codes like the following:

```
with open('users/users.txt') as f:
    {int(k): v for line in f for (k, v) in (line.strip().split(None, 1),)}
```

Which come to no use. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well the first question comes to mind - what did you expect that line of code to do, vs. what it is actually doing, or not doing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a text file that's laid out like so:

```
username1 password1
username2 password2
...
```

From what I gathered from your question, you wish to parse this file and store the results in a dictionary (i.e. username key maps to password value). This sort of stuff is more appropriately stored in a database (SQLite is built-in to Python, for instance), so you should definitely look into learning about databases rather than using a plain text file for data storage, especially user accounts.

Also, you should think about how you should store sensitive information like passwords using techniques such as hashing, but that's something you can think about when you want to make the next step (I'm under the assumption this is a small learning project, so concepts like databases and hashing might be beyond your current scope, but they are absolutely worth learning).

As for your question, you could think about doing something like the following:

```
accounts = dict()

with open('users.txt') as f:
    for account in f:
        (usr, pwd) = account.strip().split()
        accounts[usr] = pwd

print(accounts)
```

I think code clarity is more important than keeping it all in one line! The code that I have shown isn't exhaustive, more like a guideline. As I said before, I don't recommend you go this route, so definitely look into databases and proper password storing techniques!

What you could do in the mean time to ensure some form of security is to store the password as a hash (i.e. pwd would be a hash). Then when the user passes the password to the system you can calculate the hash and check if the hashes are equal. This would be better than dealing with plain text passwords. Python has a built-in module for hashing called hashlib. I'm not an expert on hashing, but this would be a decent starting point.